# Why does Windows have 5-7 different memory allocation routines?

Tags: windows

According to their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/comparing-memory-allocation-methods), Windows has a plethora of memory allocation functions.

- CoTaskMemAlloc
- GlobalAlloc
- HeapAlloc
- LocalAlloc
- malloc
- new
- VirtualAlloc

Considering that "the different heap allocators provide distinctive functionality by using different mechanisms, you must free memory with the correct function," what advantage is their to having these various routines?

Is there some historical reason why the list of allocation routines grew?

Comment: They all allocate differently. Originally it was `GlobalAlloc` for allocating selectors and `LocalAlloc` for allocations within a selector. COM has its own allocator in order to support cross-process memory sharing and to support `IMallocSpy`. `VirtualAlloc` is for allocating virtual memory, and `HeapAlloc` is for allocations within a virtual memory block. The last two aren't even part of Windows. `malloc` is for C. `new` is for C++.

Comment: HeapAlloc seems to be recommended over GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc. I assume this wasn't because the latter two were designed to be undesirable. Why were they ever created?

Comment: As for VirtualAlloc, are there general purpose uses for this? I would assume that the virtualization of memory is the OS's job, and I don't want to manage it. Unless I were writing a hypervisor or something, why would I want to allocate memory in this way?

Comment: Was VirtualAlloc just added to the list of allocation routines to be thorough?

Comment: LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc are from 16-bit Windows and were the only allocation functions available. If they weren't created, there would be no way to allocate memory at all. VirtualAlloc is the 32-bit low level allocation function.

Comment: So why don't other OSes have legacy allocation routines like these?

Comment: I don't think there was a16bit version of Linux or iOS. Note that Linux has malloc, new, brk, shmem, mmap...